# iOS version increment

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, app-store, versioning

We're in a pre-release stages of our mobile game, and it's been mostly tested on android devices. As we get closer, we started to run tests on iOS devices and noticed that the same versioning that works great on Android is not working for iOS.

Our version is automatically increased and looks like this: Major.Minor.Commit

We've noticed, that in TestFlight a version **1.0.9** would be higher in the hierarchy than **1.0.10**.

In [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2420/_index.html) it is pointed that a version - is a string that consists of up to 3 **integers** separated by a dot. If it is an integer, how come 9 is higher than 10? I assume that AppStore treat this number as a decimal, but this is not what the documentation suggesting.

The solution we found so far is to use only Major and Minor versions in the version string, and assign an incremented build number, but it's not ideal, as we would like to have similar version strings in both Android and iOS versions of the game.

So far I haven't found a proper explanation to this, and it could be that this is only a display bug in the developer dashboard.

Comment: TestFlight is clearly wrong, submit a bug report.